# error: argument COMMAND: invalid choice: 'activate' . Cannot activate conda environment in VSCode while it works perfectly in a command window

Tags: python, anaconda

Activations and deactivations work perfectly fine in a powershell prompt.

[image: powershellactivation]

In VSCode terminal "activate" is no longer a valid choice.

[image: vscodeactivatenotvalid]

I have searched far and wide for an answer to this problem, and in every case, the "answer" claimed is that I have an old version of conda and need to update. This is clearly not the case, as the versions match identically between the VSCode terminal and a powershell window.

[image: versionsmatchexactly]

Anyone have ideas of how to proceed here?

Comment: hi, did you end up solving the problem? I'm getting the same error

Comment: @Linus  The solution is to activate the python virtual environment on a command line and then start VScode from the command line.   If you have a directory of source code, you would perform `C:\msvscode\bin\code .`   Alternatively, if you have a project, substitute the `.` period with the project file.